# What JavaScript functions are available in the CouchDB map and reduce view functions?

Tags: javascript, couchdb

When writing map and reduce view functions for CouchDB in JavaScript, what are the build-in functions available?

For example, various examples refer to the following 2 functions: `emit(key, value)` and `sum(values)`. Are there other functions like `avg(values)` available?

Where can I find a full list of all functions available?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the CouchDB internals, however, from reading the sources, it looks like the map functions are [evaluated](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/util.js#L64) in the sandbox created by [`init_sandbox()`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/loop.js#L16). So the available "global" functions are the ones you see added to it. For example:

- [`require()`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/util.js#L107)
- [`log()`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/util.js#L149)
- [`isArray()`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/util.js#L159)
- [`sum()`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/trunk/share/server/views.js#L76)
- ...

`_sum` and `_count`, instead, are [built-in reduce functions](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions) written in Erlang, and you can only use them as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Well first: not CacheDB but CouchDB (header).
Second: these are not built-in Javascript functions - these are just built-in functions which work in Erlang. As far as i know there are only _sum and _count functions available.