# CouchDB: list of Erlang functions

Tags: javascript, erlang, couchdb, trim, seamonkey

As I know, CouchDB allows to use some integrated Erlang functions like a `sort` (and something else).

Doing text trimming in JS again, I thought: what if Couch already built this feature in? Maybe `trim` also integrated? And how much functions are ready to use?

If they are already done in Erlang, why I must use slow JS-versions?

So, that's my question:  where I can find full list of available from JS functions for Couch?

---

Conclusion: it only a few of functions available and there's no `trim`. You can test your luck by writing your own functions at `couch_query_server.erl` and then rebuilding Couch from source.

Comment: You want to know the list of Erlang functions (standard library) which can be used inside *CouchDB Erlang View*? If so, just take a look at their official documentation such as [string](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html) and so on.

Comment: Not Erlang View, but JS views, handlers and anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> CouchDB has three built-in reduce functions. These are implemented in Erlang and run right inside CouchDB, so they are much faster than the equivalent JavaScript functions.

They are `_count`, `_sum` and `_stats`. You can find more details and examples [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Built-In_Reduce_Functions). They are implemented in [`couch_query_server.erl`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-couch/blob/master/src/couch_query_servers.erl) file.

Also you can use built-in Erlang functions and features with writing **[Native Erlang Query Server](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/config/query-servers.html)**. But notice that it is disabled by default.

An example from CouchDB documentation for implementing a native Erlang query server:

```
%% Map Function
fun({Doc}) ->
  <<K,_/binary>> = proplists:get_value(<<"_rev">>, Doc, null),
  V = proplists:get_value(<<"_id">>, Doc, null),
  Emit(<<K>>, V)
end.

%% Reduce Function
fun(Keys, Values, ReReduce) -> erlang:length(Values) end.
```

It uses `proplists:get_value/3` and `erlang:length/1` MFAs (Module Function Arity) which are in Erlang standard library.

**Edit:** [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076433/what-javascript-functions-are-available-in-the-couchdb-map-and-reduce-view-funct) can be a possible duplicate which seems to be outdated.

Comment: That's all? There's no more functions?

Comment: That's strange why so needed functions are not built-in for speed optimization.

Comment: Or maybe there's a way that I can define functions like that manually?

Comment: I'm talking about extending js by Erlang functions. E.g. defining `trim` function in Erlang and use from JS.

Comment: @ArmanHayots I don't know if there is such solution in CouchDB, but projects like [erlang_js](https://github.com/basho/erlang_js) which is used inside [Riak](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv) might be interesting.

Comment: Another question about Couch, you're welcome. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34725149