# CouchDB update handlers: document id must not be empty

Tags: javascript, couchdb, seamonkey, nosql

I wrote simple update handler:

```
 {
   "handler": "function (doc, req) { if (req.userCtx.roles.indexOf('editor') < 0) return [req.userCtx, 'access error']; if (!doc) { return [doc, 'nothing']; } doc.date = new Date(); doc.edited_by = req.userCtx.name; return [doc, toJSON(doc)]; }"
}
```

When I'm trying to query from Mozilla HttpRequester  `http://192.168.0.34:5984/records/_design/records/_update/handler`, i'm getting

with that's data

```
{"title":"testtest","content":"test"}
```

And getting

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"Document id must not be empty"}
```

I've added `_id` to JSON

```
{"_id":"testid","title":"testtest","content":"test"}
```

No luck.

---

Update: and running that query in browser returns `nothing`, which may indicate that there's no document sent, but that's not true. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which HTTP method are you using?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In CouchDB update handler `_id` never been set automatically, so you must do it manually. The simplest solution is using `uuids`, which available at `req.uuid`.

---

One important thing about update handlers. Their syntax someplace strange: you can't take data and return doc, no. Your update handler taking `doc` and `req` objects, where first is a changing document (check document existence using `!doc`, if it returns `true` — you can create new) and the second is request data, including access info, uuid and body. We're getting data from server not in `req`, but in `req.body`, which is raw string. Is must be parsed first using `JSON.parse(req.body)`. After doing some checks, we can return — but return also not easy. If we have a doc — we're changing it, if not — we're creating new object. Return must be done by array `[data_to_be_written, return_data]`, where first item is document for database and the second is a string (and only string, use `toJSON(object)` to return objects).

---

In addition there's my update handler function example, there's a lot of dirty debug code and it can be wrong, but it working on creation (update still unchecked).

```
function (doc, req) {
    if (req['userCtx']['roles'].indexOf('editor') < 0) {
        return [null, 'Access denied'];
    }
    var rcv = JSON.parse(req.body);
    if (!doc) {
        if (!rcv['_id'] && !!rcv['title'] && !!rcv['content']) {
            return [{ '_id':req.uuid,'title': rcv['title'], 'content': rcv['content'], 'date': new Date(), 'edited_by': req['userCtx']['name'] }, 'Created' + toJSON(req)];
        }
        return [null, 'Empty' + toJSON({ 'no_id': !rcv['_id'], 'title': !!rcv['title'], 'content': !!rcv['content'], 'body':req.body })];
    }
    doc['date'] = new Date();
    doc['edited_by'] = req['userCtx']['name'];
    return [doc, 'Edited' + toJSON(doc)];
}
```

---

P.S> and remember, that even update handler working over validation func, so if your data can't pass validation, it will not be written anyway.